# Regular expression for mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have three records in mysql:

**1.** `a:7:{s:10:"state_name";s:11:"West Bengal";s:7:"city_id";a:40:{i:0;s:4:"1166";i:1;s:4:"1454";i:2;s:4:"1455";i:3;s:4:"1456";i:4;s:4:"1458";i:5;s:4:"1459";i:6;s:4:"1460";i:7;s:4:"1461";i:8;s:4:"1463";i:9;s:4:"1464";i:10;s:4:"1465";i:11;s:4:"1466";i:12;s:4:"1468";i:13;s:4:"1469";i:14;s:4:"1470";i:15;s:4:"1471";i:16;s:4:"1473";i:17;s:4:"1474";i:18;s:4:"1475";i:19;s:4:"1476";i:20;s:4:"1478";i:21;s:4:"1479";i:22;s:4:"1480";i:23;s:4:"1481";i:24;s:4:"1483";i:25;s:4:"1484";i:26;s:4:"1485";i:27;s:4:"1486";i:28;s:4:"1488";i:29;s:4:"1489";i:30;s:4:"1490";i:31;s:4:"1491";i:32;s:4:"1493";i:33;s:4:"1494";i:34;s:4:"1495";i:35;s:4:"1496";i:36;s:4:"1498";i:37;s:4:"1499";i:38;s:4:"1500";i:39;s:4:"1501";}s:6:"gender";s:4:"male";s:3:"age";s:0:"";s:12:"category_ids";s:2:"68";s:16:"product_type_ids";s:2:"30";s:18:"min_purchase_price";s:1:"0";}`

**2.** `a:7:{s:10:"state_name";s:11:"West Bengal";s:7:"city_id";a:8:{i:0;s:4:"1465";i:1;s:4:"1466";i:2;s:4:"1467";i:3;s:4:"1471";i:4;s:4:"1475";i:5;s:4:"1476";i:6;s:4:"1478";i:7;s:4:"1479";}s:6:"gender";s:0:"";s:3:"age";s:4:"0-30";s:12:"category_ids";s:2:"58";s:16:"product_type_ids";s:0:"";s:18:"min_purchase_price";s:2:"50";}`

**3.** `a:7:{s:10:"state_name";s:11:"West Bengal";s:7:"city_id";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1475";}s:6:"gender";s:6:"female";s:3:"age";s:4:"0-30";s:12:"category_ids";s:2:"58";s:16:"product_type_ids";s:0:"";s:18:"min_purchase_price";s:3:"100";}`
with the column name `conditions_serialized`.

Now I am trying to write a sql query to fetch all the records having `city_id` 1475.
My code is like :

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `rule_coupons`.`code` FROM `salesrule` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `salesrule_coupon` AS `rule_coupons` ON main_table.rule_id = rule_coupons.rule_id AND rule_coupons.is_primary = 1 WHERE (conditions_serialized regexp 'city_id";a:[0-9]*:{.*(i:[0-9]*;s:[0-9]*:"1475";)}')
```

But by this only 2 records are displaying 2nd and 3rd, not the first one.
Could you please check my query and rectify that why it is not displaying all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't search the serialized data. Extract the data you'll be using in your `WHERE` clause later and store it in a separate column (this will allow indexing and normalisation)

Comment: Your regex is trying to match the closing brace straight after matching `1475`. This should only match when `city_id 1475` is the last city in the array - this is the case in example 3.

Comment: using json serialization would be much better than php serialization, however as @hd mentioned store the data in separate columns or consider using a vertical table.

Comment: Try changing your regexp to `'city_id";a:[0-9]*:{.*(i:[0-9]*;s:[0-9]*:"1475";)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking explicitly for **1475**

```
city_id";a:[0-9]*:{.*(i:[0-9]*;s:[0-9]*:"**1475**";)}
```

change it to this instead to get records from the 3 records. Note: from 3 to 5 digits

```
city_id";a:[0-9]*:{.*(i:[0-9]*;s:[0-9]*:"\d{3,5}";)}
```